# API call on click of link in angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to call an api on click of a link and show the data in a new view , but i am not seeing any data neither an error on console.I tried using Log also but thats also not giving me any clue.
Here is my code in View:

```
        <tr class="well-new" ng-repeat="product in gettempdata.FoodItems| orderBy:'Id' | filter:search"">
            <td class="tdCenter" >
               {{product.Id}}
            </td>
            <td class="tdCenter">
                <img ng-src="{{product.ImageUrl}}" alt="{{product.Name}}" />

            </td>

            <td>
                <a href="#Name" ng-click="GetItemDetails(product.Id)"><b>{{product.Name}}</b></a><br />
                {{product.Category}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I am trying to call GetItemDetails(Id).
Controller code:

```
     myStore.controller("Home", function ($scope, StoreService, $log, $window) {
 var onComplete = function (data) {
        $scope.gettempdata = data;
    }
    var onError = function (reason) {
        alert(reason.errorcode);
    }
$scope.GetItemDetails = function (Id) {
        $log.info("wait for 5 secs");
        StoreService.getItemDetails(Id).then(onComplete, onError);
        $log.info("done");
    }
});
```

App.js code:

```
var myStore = angular.module('groceries', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when("/Home", {
            templateUrl: "/Index.html",
            controller: "Home"
        }).

        when("/Name", {
            templateUrl: "Store/Product.html",
            controller: "Home"
        }).

    otherwise
    ({
        redirectTo: "/Home"
    })

});
```

The Home view:

```
<html ng-app="groceries">
<head>
<script> ALL scripts</scripts>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- 
        bootstrap fluid layout
        (12 columns: span 10, offset 1 centers the content and adds a margin on each side)
    -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span10 offset1">
                <h1 class="well">

                    <b>Store </b>
                </h1>
                <!-- <a href="#Index.html">Click here to navigate to Store</a>-->
                <div ng-view ></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: looking at the code it seems that the gettempdata is empty when the page is loaded, and the ng-repeat won't generate anything, so you can't call the function on the anchor. :-/

Comment: Please check the case of the variables, .id instead of .Id

Comment: @toskv yes thats true ,gettempdata  is empty on page load.

Comment: @TonyBao ..The method call is not getting the ID.i.e. GetItemDetails(Id) is not getting the ID.

Comment: @toskv-- How can be routing and API call done on single click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchor tag has precedence for href over ng-click and so that won't work.
I modifed my code as below:

```
 <td >
 <a ng-href="" ng-click="GetItemDetails(product.Id,window.location.href='/Name')"><b>{{product.Name}}</b></a><br /></td>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check the case of the variables, .id instead of .Id

{{product.id}} {{product.imageUrl}}{{product.name}}{{product.category}}

Comment: how can be api call and routing done on single click